# How can I create an interactive program that ask for user's full name and display it everytime he wants to try again?

Tags: java

My code looks like this; it get's an error on line 18

> error: bad operand types for binary operator '==' if(answer=='y'||answer=='Y') {

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FullName {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String firstName = " ", middleName = " ", lastName = " ";
        String in;  // checks for input
        String answer;  // checks for condition, YES OR NO
        boolean ask;    // use as a loop switch
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Please indicate your full name: ");
            in = scan.nextLine();
            ask = scan.hasNext(in);
            String str = String.format("My name is %s %s %s ", firstName, middleName, lastName);
            System.out.println("Do you want to try again? (Y/N )");
            answer = scan.Next();
            if(answer=='y' || answer=='Y') {
                ask = true;
            } else {
                ask = false;
            }
        } while(ask == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Variable `answer` is a `String`. You are trying to compare a `String` to a `char`. You cannot do that in Java. Try: `if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just focus on these lines:

```
    String answer;
    ...
    answer = scan.next();
    if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y') {
```

1. You will notice that I have tweaked the the style to make it more readable and consist with common Java style rules.
2. You will notice that I have fixed a compilation error by changing `Next()` to `next()`.

But now for the interesting part:

```
  answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y'
```

What you are trying to do here is test if the user is trying to reply in the affirmative or the negative; i.e. a response to your `"(Y/N)" question.

There are both technical and logical problems in the way you are doing it.  The technical problem is that `answer == 'y'` tries to compare a `String` and a `char` using `==`.  Java doesn't allow that.

- This is what the compilation error about "bad operand types for `==`" is saying.
- `String` and `char` are different types.
- `'Y'` and `"Y"` are not the same value.
- Expressions of the form "string == char" or "char == string" are not allowed.
- You shouldn't compare strings using `==` anyway; see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832).

So if you were just going to compare (one character) `String` with a `char`, there are a few ways to do it; e.g.

```
answer.charAt(0) == 'y'
```

or

```
Character.toString('y').equals(answer)
```

(In this context `charAt(0)` is safe.  You are using the default `Scanner` delimiter, so `next()` is going to return a `String` with length of at least 1.)

But it would be simpler to do a `String` to `String` comparison:

```
answer.equals("y")
```

or

```
"y".equals(answer)
```

The latter has the advantage *in some contexts* that `"y"` can never be `null` so you will avoid possible NPEs.

Now for the logical problem.  You have asked the user to respond to a `(Y/N)` question.  But you are actually using `Scanner` to read a word (loosely speaking) so you may get one character, or more than one.  Also, you are assuming that if the answer is not `y` or `Y`, then that means "no".  But what if the user enters `"yes"` ... or `"fish"`?  There are more possible answers to consider than the ones that you are expecting.

If I was marking this exercise, I would deduct a mark or two (out of ten) for not properly validating the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer variable is not stored as a string, change its variable type to char.
Also, use the following code to get the letter entered by the user.

```
answer = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

Use the following

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FullName {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String firstName = " ", middleName = " ", lastName = " ";
        String in;  // checks for input
        char answer;  // checks for condition, YES OR NO
        boolean ask;    // use as a loop switch
    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        do {
            System.out.print("Please indicate your full name: ");
            in = scan.nextLine();
            //ask = scan.hasNext(in);
            String str = String.format("My name is %s %s %s ", firstName, middleName, lastName);
            System.out.println("Do you want to try again? (Y/N )");
            answer = scan.next().charAt(0);
            if(answer=='y' || answer=='Y') {
                ask = true;
            } else {
                ask = false;
            }
            scan.nextLine();
        } while(ask == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Since the answer variable is not stored as a string, change its variable type to `char`."* - That won't work.  There is no `Scanner` method to read a single `char`.